# Use NextToken to parse next results using javascript aws-sdk

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am new to JavaScript. I am running the following request;

```
ec2.describeSpotPriceHistory(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else     console.log(data); 
});
```

and it is returning a json blob with;

```
{ SpotPriceHistory:
   [ { InstanceType: 'm3.medium',
       ProductDescription: 'Linux/UNIX',
       SpotPrice: '0.011300',
       Timestamp: Tue May 03 2016 18:35:28 GMT+0100 (BST),
       AvailabilityZone: 'eu-west-1c' }],
  NextToken: 'cVmnNotARealTokenYcXgTockBZ4lc' }
```

Which is all fine. I understand that I need to use the NextToken and loop back over to get the next 100 results. How might I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the token as the `NextToken` property in your `params` object and call `describeSpotPriceHistory` again.

Something like this:

```
function getSpotPriceHistory(params) {
    ec2.describeSpotPriceHistory(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
        else     {
            console.log(data); 
            if (data.nextToken) {
                params.nextToken = data.nextToken;
                getSpotPriceHistory(params)
            }                
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How do I take the `NextToken` value from the JSON output and pass that in to the command again?

Comment: @Ste-3PO I added an example to my answer

Answer (score 5):

I did it like that, did not going to the next token inside the request just added a while loop for the nextToken with async await syntax.

```
async function fetchCurrentUsersInGroup(groupName) {
    let users = [];
    let response = {};
    let params = {
        GroupName: groupName,
        UserPoolId: 'XXXX', 
        Limit: 60
    };

    response = await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsersInGroup(params).promise();
    users = [...users, ...response.Users];

    while(response.NextToken) {
        params.NextToken = response.NextToken;
        response = await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsersInGroup(params).promise();
        users = [...users, ...response.Users];
    }

    return users;
}
```

Comment: This was very clean and helpful.